# How to set Link field value via entity metada wrapper?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using [Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) field.

I need to populate link field programmatically. Currently I'm using EMW a lot, so I'm wonder if it possible to set Link field value via EMW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$node = node_load(nid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$link = array(
  'url' => 'url',
  'title' => 'title',
  'attributes' => array()
);
$wrapper->field_link->set($link);
$wrapper->save();
```

Don't missing **$wrapper->save();**

Answer (score 3):

If your Link field is multivalue, use this code:

```
  $node = node_load(nid);
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $wrapper->field_link[] = array(
     'url' => 'url',
     'title' => 'title',
     'attributes' => array()
   );
  $wrapper->save();
```